# Issue with creating equilateral triangle using pgfplots and vertices of triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I simply want to create an equilateral triangle in LaTeX using pgfplots. I have computed the vertices of the triangle, and am using \addplot coordinates to connect them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=none,
            xmin=-1,xmax=1,
            ymin=-1,ymax=1,
            xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels=\empty, yticklabels=\empty,
        ]

            \addplot coordinates {(0, -1) (-{sqrt(3)/2}, 0.5) ({sqrt(3)/2}, 0.5) (0, -1)};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, the resulting triangle is visually not an equilateral triangle, and instead is isosceles. Is this a scaling issue, or an issue with pgfplots itself? Hopefully my math isn't wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the option `axis equal` added to key-value list of `axis` environment.

In `axis` environment, by default the plot is scaled to a 240pt x 207pt rectangle (see documentation of `\axisdefaultwidth` and `\axisdefaultheight` in [`pgfplots`' manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)), so that the unit length for x and y axis are usually different.

Comment: My sincere compliments for your 10k.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks. I never thought I can be this far. And the 2.5k earned from single answer under [_How to dynamically create a cumulative score table with hyperlinks?_](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553870/79060) dramatically accelerate the journey to 10k. :)